# How to Re-size Divs Without Stretching or Squishing Them?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, resize

I'm at a loss. I've literally tried to figure this out for four hours straight and I give up. I can't figure out how to actually use bootstrap (or just regular CSS) to prevent the elements from stretching or squishing on a page re-size. I figure there's some other sort of javascript involved, but I can't figure it out. Here is an example of what I'm talking about: http://premiumlayers.com/demos/kappe/?storefront=envato-elements

Please explain this. I'm very discouraged right now because I'm trying so hard to get good and I can't even figure this out...

Edit:

Here is some of my code:

HTML:

```css
.box {
  width:33.333%;
  height: calc(100vw / 3);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
  border:1px solid #111;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color:#222;
}

@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
  .box {
    width: 20vw;
    height: 25vh;
  }
}

@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
  .box {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 35vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="content-holder" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box">
            Box
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried using this without bootstrap but the issue continued.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code that illustrates your problem? Regular CSS elements are not resizing if they have a given width.

Comment: I edited my question to include some of my code.

Comment: Did the answers provided not help with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be handled to an extent using flexbox, however the images wouldn't take up the full width of the container until they were able to fully fit on.

In your example the boxes are resizing slightly to fit the available space and this is handled with JS.

Here is a simple example of how to handle this type of resizing:

**JS**

```
const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const box = wrap.querySelectorAll('.box');
const boxWidth = 250;

let calcBoxWidths = (function calcBoxWidths() {
  let wrapWidth = wrap.offsetWidth;
    let fitWidth = Math.round(wrapWidth / boxWidth);
    let allBoxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(box);

  allBoxes.forEach((thisBox)=>{
    thisBox.style.width = 100 / fitWidth + "%";
  });
  return calcBoxWidths;
})();

window.onresize = () => calcBoxWidths();
```

In the above JS a floored value is found for roughly how many images can fit in the width of the container. This is then turned into a percentage value to set the width of each box.

---

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/4sa9b5y8/3/

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided is using a masonry style plugin to layout the items, but for what you want you can just use viewport units.

Set the width of the `div` to a fraction of the viewport width and it will keep the aspect ratio the same when scaling down.

e.g `height: calc(100vw / 3);`

```css
.item {
  width:33.333%;
  height: calc(100vw / 3);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
  border:1px solid #111;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color:#222;
}
    
@media (max-width: 1200px) { 
  .item {
      width:33.333%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) { 
  .item {
      width:50%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) { 
  .item {
      width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
<div class="item">Item 5</div>
<div class="item">Item 6</div>
```

Comment: This kind of does, but I wanted it to respond in a way that it would be 4 boxes for a larger screen, 3 boxes for a medium screen, etc.

Comment: You need to use media queries for that to change the width of the item depending on the screen size. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I was doing that in my code, but it was stretching/squishing it.

Comment: I'm so confused, I'm sorry. Why are you taking the height and calculating it via dividing the vw by 3? Also, I put it into my code and it still doesn't work, but it works if I run it it via your snippet...sigh...